# How can I convert a multi-line batch file statement into Powershell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm in the process of converting an old batch file to Powershell.  In the batch file, the SET command is used to declare and set multiple variables, and then an executable is called that uses those variables, along with additional flags.  How would I do this in Powershell?

Batch File code excerpt:

```
SET VAR1=VAL1
SET VAR2=VAL2
SET VAR3=VAL3
SET VAR4=VAL4
%DIRECTORY%\%SUBDIR%\EXECUTABLE.EXE -FLAG1 -FLAG2 -FLAG3
```

I first attempted to declare the Powershell variables and call the exe using Start-Process, but the executable is looking for specific variable names. I'm not sure if those variables can be seen by the exe in this scenario, but it doesn't work.

```
  $VAR1 = VAL1
  $VAR2 = VAL2
  $VAR3 = VAL3
Start-Process "$DRIVE\DIR\EXECUTABLE.exe -FLAG1 -FLAG2 -FLAG3"
```

I've also unsuccessfully attempted passing the multiple line command to the command shell:

```
$Command =  "CMD.exe /C 
             SET VAR1=VAL1
             SET VAR2=VAL2
             SET VAR3=VAL3
             SET VAR4=VAL4
             $DRIVE\$DIR\EXECUTABLE.exe -FLAG1 -FLAG2 -FLAG3
Invoke-Expression $Command
```

Note** The variables have to be set on multiple lines, even when I run the exe from a DOS prompt.  Using the "&" (Batch) or ";" (Powershell) and passing all variables on one line doesn't work.

Comment: I suppose running `c:\folder1\EXECUTABLE.exe -FLAG1 -FLAG2 -FLAG3` is out of the question.

Comment: Is `-FLAG1 -FLAG2 -FLAG3` supposed to be `-%VAR1% -%VAR2% -%VAR3%`, or `$VAR1 $VAR2 $VAR3` or is it absolutely irrelevant to your question?

Comment: No, they are different values.  The variables are set, and then a different set of flags are passed to the executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For external programs (child processes) to see variables, they must be *environment* variables: use `$env:VAR1 = 'VAL1'` rather than `$VAR1 = 'VAL1'` - also note how the values must be *quoted*.

  - In `cmd.exe` (batch files), *all* variables are invariably also environment variables; in PowerShell, regular variables such as `$VAR1` are visible only to the PowerShell session itself.
- Do not use `Start-Process` to invoke external console applications, invoke them *directly* (synchronously, with standard streams connected to PowerShell's streams), using `&`, if the executable name/path is quoted and/or contains variable references; do not quote the command line *as a whole*; specify and - if necessary - quote the executable name/path and arguments *individually*.
  Similarly, [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Therefore:

```
  $env:VAR1 = 'VAL1'
  $env:VAR2 = 'VAL2'
  $env:VAR3 = 'VAL3'
  & "$DRIVE\DIR\EXECUTABLE.exe" -FLAG1 -FLAG2 -FLAG3
```